# Django read excel (xlsx) file to display in a table

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a simple excel file I am trying to figure out how I can get my app to read the excel file, so I can use the data to display in a template. I have looked into xlrd but does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas's read_excel is very easy and efficient and will also give you liberty to manipulate the columns(Fields)